# Askopenfilename alternative in Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, mobile, kivy

I'm writing a method  that allows users select existing images from their devices, is there any way  to achieve this with Kivy without using the FileChooser widget? Like being able to call the device's gallery /file manager and then select an image like with social media applications when you try to change your profile picture or upload a photo[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I doubt tkinter works on mobile devices such as Android, so as to get the regular file opening mechanisms in these platforms, you'd have to write platform specific code. For example, with Windows, tkinter askopenfilename can be used since that's the ui dialog that pops up for most other windows applications. For Android, check https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/388#thread-subscription-status. I believe tkinter should work also for Linux, and then for iOS and MacOs, research on that yourself.